# setAttribute("value", "text") doesn't work c#

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, .net-4.8

I'm messing around with the WebBrowser in C# but I'm having a little problem. When I navigate to a website and after it loads (using the DocumentCompletedEvent) I try to change the value in some input tags but they don't change neither does the button in the end. Literally nothing happens, no errors nothing. What can I do about that?

```
void onWebLoad(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", "username");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "password");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Add break point to check if the code in `onWebLoad` executed.

Comment: @KyleWang yes it is executed, and I tested the exact same command in firefox console just to make sure it wasn't something on the website's part and it works perfectly there